# Trying to upgrade to JHipster Release 5.2.1, stops on anonymous statistics prompt

Tags: jhipster

I've tried a few times now and was wondering if anyone else was having this issue?
Performing an upgrade as per the upgrade instructions on the release notes, but it freezes on this step.
I'm currently on v4.14.2 on windows 7 professional (client's prefered OS :)
Maybe if the stats collection prompt can be set via a parameter, not sure if that's an option to get passed the prompt.

[image: anonymous statistics prompt during upgrade]

Comment: Try answering the prompt during generation of a project in a different directory.  Once you answer that prompt  it should store in a global config file and not ask you again

Comment: great suggestion, I could also just add the property to the global config file, if that's an option. I'll give that a try, on a new project, thank you!

Comment: I couldn't find the file on my computer, I think it should be under `~/.config/configstore/` but I don't see it.  It should look like https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/8db81ca5338286c92253d805a9a7f9ec772685d3/travis/configstore/insight-generator-jhipster.json . Shouldn't be an issue in the future after this PR: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/8116

Comment: just tried it again on a new project, same thing happens, just halts at that prompt. I'll hold off on the upgrade for now, thanks for your responses, I'll wait for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I had Same problem and followed the suggestion of creating a new project. I created a dummy project with all defaults and was able to answer Yes. Afterwards jhispter upgrade worked on my other projects.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but it is still sticking, even in the new project.